# Does the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac { \sin^2 (x-y)}{|x|+|y|}$ exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm supposed to check if the function defined the same as the one in the limit can be expanded to be defined (and continuous) at $(0,0)$.
I think the limit is zero, because $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac { \sin^2(x-y)}{|x|+|y|} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac { \sin^2 (x-y)}{(x-y)^2}\frac{(x-y)^2}{|x|+|y|}$$
and the left multiple approaches 1 as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, while the right multiple approaches 0, following this reasoning: $$0 \leq \frac{x^2+y^2-2xy}{|x|+|y|} \leq \frac{x^2}{|x|}+ \frac{y^2}{|y|} - \frac{2xy}{|x|+|y|}$$
On the right hand side, the first two summands approach 0 as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, obviously, and the third one approaches zero because (and this is the part I'm not sure about): $$y \leq \max \{x, y\} \leq |x|+|y| \space \implies -1 \leq \frac{y}{|x|+|y|} \leq 1\land \space 2x\to 0 , (x, y) \to(0,0).$$
I'm very inexperienced with finding multivariable limits so I'm very unsure about what I can and can't assume, and I haven't in my limited experience encountered many problems where the limit actually exists (most of the problems want the solver to come up with a counterexample), so I'd appreciate any corrections or input on my reasoning.

Comment: The first equal sign is not quite right. $\sin(x^2 - y^2) \neq \sin ((x-y)^2)\neq \sin^2(x-y).$

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it was just a typo.

Comment: For the third term, you can also write $$\frac{2|xy|}{|x|+|y|} = \sqrt{|xy|}\frac{2\sqrt{|xy|}}{|x|+|y|} \leq \sqrt{|xy|}$$ where we used the fact that $2\sqrt{|xy|} \leq |x|+|y|$, which follows from $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$ with $a = \sqrt{|x|}$ and $b = \sqrt{|y|}$.

Comment: You can only multiply by $\frac{(x-y)^2}{(x-y)^2}$ for $x \neq y$, so in this case you could just note that $\sin(x-y) =0$, and thus also $\frac{\sin(x-y)}{|x|+|y|} =0$, which coincides with what you want to show.

Comment: @Bungo thank you for noting that! It's apparent that knowledge of elementary inequalities is encouraged when calculating multiple variable limits, which I have, but rarely remember to use!

Comment: @Hetebrij so my final solution was correct, but incomplete. I missed the whole line $y=x$. Thank you for correcting me!